# Conditionally replace values in a column by several, alternating values (tidyverse)

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

Suppose I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:2], each = 4),
                 A = rep(letters[3:4]),
                 B = letters[1:8])
```

I now want to conditionally replace all values in column B if column A equals "c". I want to do this in a way that the first occurrence is replaced by "x", the second occurrence by "y", then "x" again, then "y" again and so on. Additionaly, it should be done in each group separately.

So, the expected output would be:

```
  group A B
1     a c x
2     a d b
3     a c y
4     a d d
5     b c x
6     b d f
7     b c y
8     b d h
```

I tried sth. like

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>  mutate(B = ifelse(A == "c", rep(c("x", "y"), each = 0.5 * sum(A == "c")), B), .by = group)
```

but this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
df |> 
    group_by(group) |> 
    mutate(equal_c = cumsum(A == 'c')) |> 
    mutate(new_A = ifelse(
        A != 'c', 
        A, 
        c('y', 'x')[equal_c %% 2 + 1]
    ))
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   group [2]
  group A     B     equal_c new_A
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int> <chr>
1 a     c     a           1 x    
2 a     d     b           1 d    
3 a     c     c           2 y    
4 a     d     d           2 d    
5 b     c     e           1 x    
6 b     d     f           1 d    
7 b     c     g           2 y    
8 b     d     h           2 d
```

`equal_c` counts the occurrence of 'c' in each group and then we use this to alternate between 'x' and 'y' whenever A equal 'c'

Comment: Can you explain, why you started with "y", instead of "x"? In one of my attempts I also got it almost working and were wondering about the same, i.e. that the second elements was used first.

Comment: the first time we get a 'c', `equal_c` becomes 1, so `equal_c %%2 + 1` becomes 2. It alternates between 2, 1, 2, 1, ...